# Lenovo IdeaPad U410 Won't Shut Down

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, shutdown, lenovo-laptop

When I try to Shut Down through Windows it just logs off but stays on. It will shut down (instantly) if I hold the power off button. Restart works fine, it just won't shut down.

Lenovo IdeaPad U410
Windows 8.1 Pro 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

I hope the below steps will resolves your issue:

> 1) Open start menu and type "regedit" and press Enter.
>
> 2) This opens up the Registry Editor.
>
> 3) Make sure to backup you Registry before you continue. (To do so,
>   Click "File" and then "Export" and give any name to your backup file).
>
> 4) Go to the following path:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager
>
> 5) Once opened, on the right side , find the "BootExecute" entry.
>   double-click on it.
>
> 6) Delete all of its "Value Data" part and write the following into
>   it: autocheck autochk * and press OK.
>
> 7) Now, "RESTART" your computer.
>
> 8) After successful restart, press SHUTDOWN button, it should work!

Comment: Unfortunately that is the current value for that entry.